# How to get section and subsection titles in the header of a scrartcl document with scrlayer-scrpage?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

How can I get the `section` title in the left header and the `subsection` title in the right header in the KOMA-Script class `scrartcl` with `scrlayer-scrpage` in the following one-sided document?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\ohead{\leftmark}
\ihead{\rightmark}
\chead{}
\cfoot{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext[3]
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext[3]

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext[3]
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\ohead{\rightbotmark}
\ihead{\leftmark}
\chead{}
\cfoot{\pagemark}% Note: I would recommend to use `\cfoot*` instead of `\cfoot` here.

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext[3]
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext[3]

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext[3]
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]
Option `autooneside=false` is needed, because (see `scrguiden-en`, section 17.6):

> In one-sided printing, you normally want only the higher section levels to provide the running title. The default option `autooneside` corresponds to this behaviour.

`\rightbotmark` is used, because `\rightmark` is `\rightfirstmark` (see `scrguide-en`, section 17.6) and `\sectionmark` uses `\markboth`. So every `\section` before a `\subsection` on the same page, would also dominate the right mark. Another solution could be to use a construct like:

```
\ohead{\Ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}{\rightbotmark}{\rightmark}}
```

or to redefine `\sectionmark`, e.g.:

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markleft{\sectionmarkformat #1}}
```

Sometimes it could even be useful to use `\automark[section]{subsection}` instead of `\automark[subsection]{section}`, but usually not.

Note: The results of the different suggestions differ in details, e.g. if `\section` and (previous or following) `\subsection` are at the same page or not at the same page.